# Redux Toolkit: state.filter not making changes to state while state.map does

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a list of counters as defined in  `initialState`. All other functions in my `slice` are working except `deleteCounter`. I have verified the dispatch is working fine.

```
export const myCounterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'myCounter',
  initialState: [
    { id: 1, value: 4 },
    { id: 2, value: 5 },
    { id: 3, value: 8 },
    { id: 4, value: 2 }
  ],
  reducers: {
    incrementCount: (state, action) => {
      state.map(x => x.id === action.payload ? x.value += 1 : x);
    },
    resetCount: (state, action) => {
      state.map(x => x.id === action.payload ? x.value = 0 : x);
    },
    deleteCounter: (state, action) => {
      state.filter(x => x.id != action.payload)
    },
    resetAllCount: (state) => {
      state.map(x => x.value = 0);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immer works by tracking *mutations* to existing Proxy-wrapped values, or letting you *return* a new state value:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#mutating-and-returning-state

Your code isn't doing either of those. `.filter()` functions returns a new array. Because you have curly braces on the reducer functions, you must use the `return` keyword to actually return some new state value.  So, you'd need to do `return state.filter()` for Immer to see any of these updates.

On the other hand, your `.map()` calls are actually mutating the item it's looping over, with `x.value += 1` and `x.value = 0`. That's normally a bad thing for a map() function to be doing - `map()` should never be used to mutate values, in or out of `Immer`. It's the wrong method conceptually. If you want to write mutating code in a loop, use `forEach` so that other programmers know what to expect.

Comment: but all other are working except `deleteCounter`

Comment: and also if you will see official documentation/example there is no return keyword even though curly braces are used. https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#redux-toolkit-example

Comment: As I said, Immer allows "mutating" syntax, which is why the example has no `return`. On the other hand, your `.map()` calls are actually _mutating_ the item it's looping over, with `x.value += 1` and `x.value = 0`. That's normally a bad thing for a `map()` function to be doing - `map()` should never be used to mutate values, in or out of Immer. It's the wrong method conceptually. If you want to write mutating code in a loop, use `forEach` so that other programmers know what to expect.

Comment: Thx, got it. The link you shared clarifies. yes returning the state is working with `deleteCounter`. I tried assigning the result of filter again to state without returning but it didn't work? any thoughts